# How can I most easily access Netflix on Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, netflix

In order to access Netflix on my Xbox 360, I have to

1. Turn the system on, usually by holding the Xbox Guide button
2. Wait for the system to load
3. Press the Xbox Guide button again to bring up the mini menu
4. Press X and select my Gold account (rather than my wife's Silver account) and press A to sign in
5. Wait for Xbox Live to finish transmitting data
6. Press the Xbox Guide button again to bring up the mini menu again
7. Press left to get out of the Accounts pane and select Quick Launch before pressing A
8. Press right twice to get to "All Downloads" (rather than Recent Games or Recent Downloads)
9. Select Netflix from the list and press A

This is needlessly cumbersome. It's true that I can configure some steps to go a little more smoothly (like not automatically loading the current disc when system is powered on, or by automatically signing when the system is powered on, although my wife might complain about the latter), but it still feels like the Netflix app is buried in the menus compared to practically anything else on the system; as far as I can tell, you can't even access it through Xbox Live's main dashboard. I can only find it through Quick Launch > All Items.

Is there a better way to do this that I don't know about?

Comment: Avoid going through the dashboard to launch anything if at all possible, it just takes too long.

Answer (score 9):

The following works for me, once you're signed in with your Gold account and at the dashboard:

1. Go up to Video Marketplace (3 above Spotlight, which is selected for me initially)
2. Go right to Netflix (two to the right as of this writing)
3. Press A to run Netflix

Comment: Why did you still have the spotlight channel enabled?

Answer (score 5):

On my Xbox Netflix is on the Video Marketplace row of the dashboard, which is accessed by pressing up twice from the My Xbox row. Netflix is then the third item on that row.

Comment: ...huh. I thought I'd searched the Video Marketplace row pretty thoroughly, but I'll double-check this when I get home. Thanks!